# Thrift : TFramedTransport total payload length

Tags: thrift

I am writing a decoder to decode and print out Thrift Messages along with other protocol messages stored in a PCAP file.

When I look at Thrift packets, For some Thrift messages I see total length information in the payload ( first 4 bytes) followed by Thrift Message ( 80 01...).

For some other THrift messages, I dont see total length information in the packet but it is sent out in a separate packet ( payload size of 4) just before the Thrift packet is sent out.

Investigating further I found out that using TFramedTransport sends out total length information but why is it not sent out for some Thrift messages?

Thanks,
 Prabhakar

Comment: I am using Thrift 0.6.xxx version